# Login failed show error message from php in android

Tags: php, android

I am new in android development and I'm trying to follow this login tutorial using volley https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial/. I follow and it works perfectly. But when i try to login it gives me the error respone from my php webservice.

LoginActivity.class

```
private void loginUser( final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String cancel_req_tag = "login";
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging you in...");
        showDialog();
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL_FOR_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    if (!error) {
                        String user = jObj.getJSONObject("USER_ID").getString("LASTNAME");
                        // Launch User activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                LoginActivity.this,
                                CameraTestActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username", user);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        //show error output in my login screen

                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("USER_ID", email);
                params.put("LASTNAME", password);
                return params;
            }
```

login.php

```
  <?php
    require_once 'dbConnect.php';


    $response = array("error"=> FALSE);

  if(isset($_POST['USER_ID'])) {
         echo "my echo response";


        $username = $_POST['USER_ID'];
        $password = md5($_POST['LASTNAME']);



        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

       $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_UserDetails  WHERE USER_ID= ? AND LASTNAME= ?");
        $query->execute(array($username,$password));

        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        Database::disconnect();


    } 



        if (!(empty($row))){

            $response["error"]= FALSE;
            $response["user"]["ID"]=$row["USER_ID"];
        $response["user"]["LASTNAME"]=$row["LASTNAME"];
            echo json_encode($response);    



        }
        else{
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
//It show this message even I correctly input the correct username and password
            $response["error_msg"] = "Wrong credentials!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }



    ?>
```

login.php response:

```
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}
```

Can you please help me to make my login works ?

Comment: it might be due your POJO class, or maybe the request you are trying to send, you should consider using firebase as an easy/friendly alternative to log users

Comment: thanks for suggestion but is their any way how to make that code works ?

Comment: did you tried triming your textviews with trim() , maybe they are causing some problems when you input your credentials

Comment: $username = $_POST['17038'];//Correct Username from DB
$password = md5($_POST['CHRIST']);//correct pass from db, I tried to . But it still give me the {"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your **PDO** statements.

change

```
         $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_UserDetails ");
         $query->execute(array($username,$password));
```

to

```
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_UserDetails  WHERE name= ? AND password= ?");
        $query->execute(array($username, $password));
```

there is another problem.

```
 if(isset($_GET['USER_ID']))
```

this condition is never satisfied.
because you are making a `POST`  request from your android client
so change it to

```
 if(isset($_POST['USER_ID']))
```

**NOTE:**

change column names in my answers to yours as in your database.

also, see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) about PDO `prepare()`

Comment: try to debug your PHP code.print the name and password sent fro phone

Comment: $username = $_POST['17038'];//Correct Username from DB $password = md5($_POST['CHRIST']);//correct pass from db, I tried to . But it still give me the {"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}. Any idea?

Comment: Thank You I follow your instruction but it still giving me the same errro and still my php response is {"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}.Here is what Im trying:                                      
 $username = $_POST['17038'];//Correct Username from DB $password = md5($_POST['CHRIST']);//correct pass from db, I tried to . But it still give me the {"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}.

Comment: It must show the column of the USER_ID ="17038" and LASTNAME= "CHRIST" right? but its stil givem e the {"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}. Im having hard time to figure out

Comment: add an echo statement inside the if(isset) .to find out it enters this block or not

Comment: no I just wanted you to debug your code. put the link in browser to see the output

Comment: yeah..it still the same..{"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}

Comment: give me the url